# How to tell if browser/tab is active, and turn down volume sound when user leave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I check if the page is open in the active tab? I want to mute video on my website, when user leave tab. Currently I'm using:

```
$(window).on('focus', function() {
    $("video").prop('muted', false);
});
```

but when user click on adressbar video is muted, so this is unexpected. Can I avoid this behavior? The best solution is something like at this webpage: http://volkswagen-sportscars.fr/cars/ when user open other tabs in browser, sounds is smoothly turned down. How it's made?

Comment: Have you actually looked at the javascript source that's being used on their site, or are you just asking us first?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active

Comment: yes, I saw this, but this not answered at mine question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Newer browsers (IE10 and up) have support for the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API)

> The Page Visibility API lets you know when a webpage is visible or in
>   focus. With tabbed browsing, there is a reasonable chance that any
>   given webpage is in the background and thus not visible to the user.
>   When the user minimizes the webpage or moves to another tab, the API
>   sends a visibilitychange event regarding the visibility of the page.
>   You can detect the event and perform some actions or behave
>   differently. For example, if your web app is playing a video, it would
>   pause the moment the user looks at another browser, and plays again
>   when the user returns to the tab. The user does not lose their place
>   in the video and can continue watching.

Used something like this

```
var hidden, visibilityChange;
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "hidden";
    visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "mozHidden";
    visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "msHidden";
    visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
    hidden = "webkitHidden";
    visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);

function handleVisibilityChange() {
    $("video").prop('muted', document[hidden]);
}
```

[**DEMONSTRATION**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/KCGZ8/)